# Find the maximum distance between $y= x + \sin x$ and $y = x$ on $[0,\pi]$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Also, is there a way to recreate the distortion to the sine curve when $x$ is added while keeping everything down on the $x$-axis?  In other words, the curve $y = x + \sin x$ where $y = x$ is the $x$-axis.

Comment: I can think of a few ways to do this using calculus, but from the algebra-precalculus tag I assume you don't want such a solution?

Comment: what do you mean by distance in this context?

Comment: Perhaps you could consider rotating the graphs by the rotation matrix?

Answer (score 2):

The closest point to $(x_0,y_0)$ on the line $y=x$ is $((x_0+y_0)/2, (x_0 + y_0)/2)$.  Thus the distance from the point to the line is $|x_0 - y_0|/\sqrt{2}$.  With $y_0 = x_0 + \sin(x_0)$, the distance is $|\sin(x_0)|/\sqrt{2}$.  This is maximized when $\sin(x_0) = \pm 1$, i.e. $x_0$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$y = x + sin(x)$ so $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + cos(x)$.  The maximum value wrt. $y=x$ will occur where the tangent line has slope of $1$.

$1 + cos(x) = 1$ yields $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and the corresponding $y$ value would be $\frac{\pi}{2} + 1$, so one of our points will be $(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} + 1)$

To find our other point, we need to draw a perpendicular wrt $y = x$ from this point, this line will have slope $m = -1$ and will cross through the point $(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} + 1)$.  We use $y = mx + b$ and all our data to get $b = \pi + 1$ and thus our line is $y = -x + \pi + 1$.

Now we see where this line crosses the line $y = x$.  Set $x = -x + \pi + 1$ and it yields $x = \frac{\pi+1}{2}$.  Thus our second point is: $(\frac{\pi+1}{2}, \frac{\pi+1}{2})$

Now.. how do you find the distance between two points?

As for the second part of your question, I'm not sure at the moment.

Comment: good start, but repeat the computations, second line yields $x=\pi/2$, not $\pi/4$

Comment: Also this is tagged algebra-precalculus